# Teamcity pytest plugin & unit test reporting

Tags: python, teamcity, pytest

We have recently moved away from our custom test runner / discovery tool in favor of py.test.  For proper unit test reporting when running under teamcity there exists a pytest plugin: https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-python

When installed with:

> python setup.py install

The plugin is discovered correctly by pytest. However, we don't want to install pytest & this plugin on our build machines. Instead we would rather have them packaged as part of our projects "tools" directory.

How do install / configure py.test to "discover" this plugin.  We have tried adding `pytest_plugins = "teamcity"` with several variations to the setup.cfg file of pytest with no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "pytest_plugins" configuration variable (see output at the end of "py.test -h).  However, the env var "PYTEST_PLUGINS" contains comma-separated python import paths.  So if you plugin is in "teamcity/util/myplugin.py" you would set it like this:

```
export PYTEST_PLUGINS=teamcity.util.myplugin
```

You can also use a command line option "-p teamcity.util.myplugin" to achieve a similar effect.  And then add it to your setup.cfg's section:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -p teamcity.util.myplugin
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the 'addopts' to my pytest configuration and it found the plugin with not difficulties.